# Pass variables between functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

I have functions that perform distance calculation with Google Maps.

They work smoothly, returning me the requested values.

This function returns a first value

```
  function calcDistance(response) {

    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;


    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
     var results = response.rows[i].elements;

     for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
   
    distanzafissa = results[j].distance.value;
    distanzafissa = distanzafissa / 1000;
    
    distanzafissarr = Math.round(distanzafissa*100)/100;
    }
   }
  }
```

I would like the value of `distanzafissarr` to pass to another function so coded:

```
    function computeTotalDistance(result) {
      var total = 0;
      var myroute = result.routes[0];
      for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
        total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
      }
      total = total / 1000;
      
      
    var totalarr = Math.round(total*100)/100;
   }
```

I have tried to follow various answers on this site, but always getting errors.

Comment: Neither function mentions the other, so it is unclear where you are trying to pass a value.

Comment: "This function returns a first value" — That function doesn't return anything. It has no `return` statement.

Comment: You also have a number of issues that a linter (e.g. ESLint) would pick up.

Comment: These two functions are part of a much larger script. As I said, they work by returning me the requested values.
My problem is that I can only use these values ​​within my own functions.
Since I will have to do a series of if ... else, I would at least like the values ​​of 'distanzafissarr' and 'totalarr' to be used outside of functions.

Reading the various answers present, I also used return, but I was always getting errors.
Of course, due to my javascript incompetence, I was making mistakes.

Comment: "These two functions are part of a much larger script" — You need to provide a [mcve] not snippets of disconnected code.

Comment: "they work by returning me the requested values" — they don't return anything

Comment: "I was always getting errors" — People can't help  you debug your errors without seeing them. See also: [ask]

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score -1):

You are not returning any value from a function so it returns *undefined*. Put **return** at the end of the function:

```
 function computeTotalDistance(result) {
      var total = result + 1;
      return total; // missing
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to make your funcions a `getter` or `return` functions like the following example.

```
function getCalculatedDistance(response) {

    let origins = response.originAddresses;
    let destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
    let distanzaFissarr;

    for (let i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
        let results = response.rows[i].elements;

        for (let j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {

            let distanzaFissa = (results[j].distance.value) / 1000;
            distanzaFissarr = Math.round(distanzaFissa * 100) / 100;
        }
    }

    return distanzaFissarr; // Return data
}


function getTotalDistance(result) {

    let total = 0;
    let myroute = result.routes[0];

    for (let i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
        total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
    }

    total = total / 1000;

    return Math.round(total * 100) / 100; // Return data
}
```

If you don't do that you function will return `undefined` so you will not get access to any of the function variables.

Check [JavaScript Scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) to determines the accessibility (visibility) of variables.

In order to use the returned data, you can do something like that

```
const calculatedDistance = getCalculatedDistance(response);
const totalDistance = getTotalDistance(result);
```